# Exercise in C - forks

Tags: c, fork

I am trying to understand how the `fork()` method works in C.  This is an example problem from my textbook:

> ```
> int
> main(void)
> {
>   pid_t process_id;
>   int status;
>
>   if (fork() == 0) { 
>     if (fork() == 0) { 
>       printf("A"); 
>     } else {
>       process_id = wait(&status);
>       printf("B");
>     }
>   } else {
>     if (fork() == 0) { 
>       printf("C");
>       exit(0);
>     }
>     printf("D");
>   }
>   printf("0");
>   return (0);
> }
> ```
>
> Which of the following outputs are possible?
>
> 1) D0A0B0C
>
> 2) CDAB000
>
> 3) DA00CB0
>
> 4) D0AB0CD
>
> 5) AD00BC0

I sketched it out on paper and I think the right answer is: 1, 3, 5. I had some difficulty working around the `wait(&status)`, though. Is my answer right?

Comment: Are you sure your environment or your program has function `Wait`, not `wait` with small `w`?

Comment: @MikeCAT oops, that is a typo. I have edited the question.

Comment: The semantics of fork and in general of forking a process can follow two distinct disjoint paths. You can either wait for the child process to terminate or run concurrently. Given these definitions, you should be able to address your problem.

Comment: @nbro I understand roughly how fork and forking work in theory but I haven't had much practice working through concrete examples.

Comment: @user6269144 `fork` initially returns a non-zero value when forking the child to the parent. When you wait for the child to terminate, a zero value is returned to the child process...

Comment: So, for example, the first thing is going to happen is that the first `fork` in the first `if` statement should return a value different from 0 (i.e. the pid of the child process), but since the condition (`fork() == 0`) is not satisfied, then the `else` is executed...

Answer (score 4):

I just worked it out and I think 1, 3, and 5 are correct.

There are 4 processes, but 2 have a dependency relationship because of the wait.
This means the possible outputs are (_ means preemption possible):

```
_A_0_B_0_
_C_
_D_0_
```

2 and 4 do not work because there is no 0 between A and B.
The wait is called in a process where fork()!=0, which means it is a parent.  The semantics of fork() are that the parent is given the process id of the child as a return value and the child gets a return value of 0.
It should be quite easy to see that 1, 3, and 5 work if you follow along the 3 above outputs.

Comment: How is that possible that 5 is correct since it starts with an `A`? The first `fork` will not be 0...

Comment: Fork is called once and returns twice.  It will be non zero in one process and zero in the other.  Four processes are made, 1) prints A then 0, 2) waits for 1) then prints B then 0, 3) prints C, and 4) prints D then 0.  It is up to the system scheduler to handle what order to run things and how things are preempted.  For 5, the system runs 1) so it prints A then preempts it with 4) which prints D0 then schedules 1) again which prints 0, then 2) is able to run and print B, which is preempted by 3) which prints C and 2) finishes with 0.

Comment: Also, the Linux scheduler can be invoked during any syscall.  fork definitely uses a syscall to create a new process.